# Correctly using glVertexPointer?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Whenever I look a tutorials that explain how to use the glDrawArrays and the glVertexPointer commands, the arguments they use are different from the ones I have available.

For example : a tutorial calls glVertexPointer with parameters like this : (Vertices is an array of floats)

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, Vertices);
```

The parameters that I have available are :

```
glVertexPointer(int size, int stride, FloatBuffer pointer);
```

My question is : What is the correct way to use glVertexPointer()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glVertexPointer`, as the name suggests, is based on using *pointers*. You're using Java, where pointers *don't exist*. Therefore, the Java equivalent has to work differently. It has to take a special memory array object, which can internally be converted into a C pointer that will be passed to the actual `glVertexPointer` call.

Because Java puts a type on the buffer's contents, you don't need an explicit type field. There are [several overloads of `glVertexPointer` in LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glVertexPointer%28int,%20int,%20java.nio.DoubleBuffer%29), each of which takes a different type of buffer.

Comment: Ok I see. I would have to do something like : IntBuffer verts = IntBuffer.wrap(Vertices) ?

Comment: @lightice11: Why would you put "an array of floats" in an *IntBuffer*?

Comment: Floats where from the tutorial I was reading, I'm using ints in my program :D Anyways, it gives me an error saying that the buffer isn't direct. Should I use the ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() instead?